# Place text label in 3D coordinates that are not data-dependent

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, label

I have a subplot containing 2x2 3-D graphs. In this graph I want to place a text box, to put some additional information.
To this end, I've found the **matplotlib.pyplot.text** function.
However, this function uses the data-coordinates as input. As my four subplots all have a different range of z-values, placing a text at a single z-coordinate will give them other relative placements.

MWE

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
for plotnr in [1,2,3,4]:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, plotnr, projection='3d')
    n = 10
    for c, m, zl, zh in [('r', 'o', -50, -25), ('b', '^', -30, -5)]:
        xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
        ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
        zs = np.divide(randrange(n, zl, zh),1000/(10**(plotnr-1)))
        ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=c, marker=m)
        ax.text(27, 60,3,'matplotlib', ha='center', va='center',transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

As you can see from the image the 'matplotlib' is moving around, or isn't even present at all. I have the idea that this is becauseo of the changing values of z.
[image: text-label misalignment]

*Is it possible to place the text box at coordinates relative to the image, rather than at coordinates relative to the data?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.py), it's possible to switch to 2D label placement using:

```
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "2D Text", transform=ax.transAxes)
```